# Change Twitter's Navbar from hortizontal to vertical

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Can i use Twitter's Navbar also in an vertical position without changing the html structure. How will this effect the elements as forms, dropdowns etc.

How should such navbar collapse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could adapt the css, something like:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    height: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    max-height: none;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    width: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-x: visible;
  }

.navbar
{
    max-width:300px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}   

.navbar-nav,
.navbar-nav > li,
.navbar-left,
.navbar-right,
.navbar-header
{float:none !important;}

.navbar-right .dropdown-menu {left:0;right:auto;}
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
}
```

Although it doesn't seems reasonable to use a navbar-right in this case the above will work for a default navbar from the docs (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).

Example: http://bootply.com/84045