# Vertical navbar Bootstrap 3.0.3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am creating a new website with Bootstrap  and wanta menu on the left and vertically, for two columns, do you know how I can do it in three Bootstrap?

I tried with nav-stacked but does not work me

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Twitter's Navbar from hortizontal to vertical](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191697/change-twitters-navbar-from-hortizontal-to-vertical)